# How Do I Add By Two in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c, auto-increment, integer

In the app that I am making, I am using a segmented button to control adding or subtracting a number by one or two, the only problem is that I dont know how to add/subrtact a number by two based on the method that I use to add or subtract by one.  This is the code that I have in my app to add or subtract by one:

```
int number = 0;

-(IBAction)IncrementNumber:(id)sender {
    number++;
    [currentNumber setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number]];
}

-(IBAction)DecrementNumber:(id)sender {
    number--;
    [currentNumber setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number]];
}
```

Based on this code, how would I go twards adding or subtracting by two or even three?

Comment: Objective-C is still C underneath. Get *The C Programming Language* by Kernighan & Ritchie, and learn C. You won't regret it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or more verbal:

```
number = number + n;
number = number - n;
```

(Where n is the number you want to add/substract.)

Answer (score 1):

```
number += 2;
number -= 2;
```

Generalization:

```
number += n;
number -= n;
```

If you have somewhere else where you are setting the amount for incrementing or decrementing something use that number as `n`.